# the woman exercising in the room

Tags: participles

a. In the room, I saw a woman sitting behind a desk reading, and a woman exercising. I greeted the woman exercising.

b. In the room, I saw a woman sitting behind a desk reading, and a woman exercising. I greeted the exercising woman.

c. In the room, I greeted a woman exercising.

d. In the room, I greeted an exercising woman.

Which of the above sentences are grammatical?

Would (c) work if the woman was the one who was exercising?

Would (c) work if I was the one who was exercising?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If, in (a)(2) you're going to interpret "I greeted the woman exercising" as "exercising" referring to "I", then in (a)(1) you could interpret "sitting," "reading," and "exercising" as referring to "I".

A "lingering image" and an "image lingering" definitely are not the same things. An "entertaining woman" is not a "woman entertaining." I think the same applies here. An "exercising woman," whatever that is, is not a "woman [who is | who was] exercising."

[]ing before a noun is an adjective. []ing after a noun is a verb. I think.

There's economy of words. And then there's nonsense.